# Compute group aggregates over a dynamic number of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a large dataset similar to the following table (called `results.raw` further down) with some independent (`X000` to `X306`) and some dependent variables (they have different names):

```
X000  X001  X002 ... X306  MEASURE1  OUT2  ... RESULTN
1     2     1        2     1         2         2
1     2     1        2     2         3         1
                 ...
2     3     1        4     5         3         3
                 ...
```

I want to average this dataset grouping whenever the independent variables are equal. I came up with the following `R` command, which seems to work, but is very slow

```
aggregate(results.raw, by = as.list(lapply(as.list(colnames(results.raw)[1:307]), FUN = function (x) { results.raw[,x] })), FUN = mean)
```

How can this be made faster?

Comment: Try with `library(dplyr); results.raw %>% group_by_at(1:307) %>% summarise_all(mean)` or `library(data.table);setDT(results.raw)[, , lapply(.SD, mean), by = c(names(results.raw)[1:307])]`

Comment: Thanks, that worked faster indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
results.raw %>% 
    group_by_at(1:307) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(results.raw)[, , lapply(.SD, mean), by = c(names(results.raw)[1:307])]
```